# TypoScript constant with uid of current page

Tags: typo3, typoscript

Is it possible to put the ID of the current page into TypoScript constant (dynamically)?

Comment: Bonus question: what are you gonna to do with that value later?

Comment: Actually, the ideas was to define some sort of TS autoloader with INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT : to autoload setup and constants from some predefined folder. So It's more easy to manage complex installations. As I undertand at the moment, the only one way to acheive this - hack the Core somewhere.

Comment: OK, don't get your idea with managing installations, however won't be it OK if you pass all required `PIDs` (and other) via setup instead of constants ?

Comment: (usually Constants values are passed to the extensions via Setup, so maybe it will be just easier do not declare constants, but rely definitely on Setup where you can set current uid without any problems)

Comment: @Fedir - 
There is extension "hype_base" that reads the TS from the folders automatically but frankly I did not used that ext yet. Additionally if you like I can send you my private extension which allows to define dynamic parts in the constants.

Comment: @biesior Yep, agree, what variables You could redefine easily, but constants it's possible to substitute with setup rendering, as it's uses str_replace method, but how could You point a variable into INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT call ? Syntactically I mean.

Comment: @Krystian As I understand in the manual of hype_base, that works with "include static templates", so need to select them manually after in the BE in the properties of the page. So, looks like not a real autoload.

Comment: @Krystian Great, I will send You a private email with the request !

Comment: @Fedir - At hype_base. From my understanding of docs what is shown in BE are folders and all files inside the selected folders are included.

Answer (score 0):

You can't since the constants are processed **before** the setup.
And as said, the constants are **constants** fixed values.

No dynamic process available for this.